# why mongoose virtual populate doesn't show up in data base?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

i want to access review's model on the tour's model , but when i want get the tour the review's doesn't exist in my data base 
here is my code

tourModel :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const slugify = require('slugify');
const validator = require('validator');
// const User = require('./userModel');

const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    guides : [
        {
            type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref : 'User'
        }
    ],
}, {
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    },
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    }
})

// Virtual populate     
tourSchema.virtual('reviews' , {
    ref : 'Review',
    foreignField : 'tour',
    localField : '_id',
    justOne : true
})

const Tour = mongoose.model('Tour', tourSchema);

module.exports = Tour;
```

Comment: If you need review in tour then why are you making it virtual?

Comment: because i think write like a child referencing is not correct way to write populate for parent referencing  , is it?